# Magento Checkout Stuck

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

When I try to decide which costs of shipping I'd like to use I cannot proceed on the onepage checkout...

Debugging says the following:
[image]

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issue with third party extension rewriting the checkout routing configuration please deactivate them and try again.Also enable template hints for find any hard code.

Comment: thanks! could you say what is meant by "hints for find any hard code"?